# python pip doesn't seem to do anything at all

Tags: python, cygwin, pip, easy-install

I'm on Cygwin.  Python and `setuptools` have been installed from the Cygwin installer.  Everything seems to be in order:

```
% which python
/usr/bin/python
% python --version
Python 2.7.5

% which easy_install
/usr/bin/easy_install
% head -n1 `which easy_install`
#!/usr/bin/python
```

I then used `easy_install` to install `pip`:

```
% easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 1.5.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.5.2.tar.gz#md5=5da30919f732d68b1c666e484e7676f5
Processing pip-1.5.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-nDQrFF/pip-1.5.2/setup.cfg
Running pip-1.5.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-nDQrFF/pip-1.5.2/egg-dist-tmp-9JbeeX
warning: no files found matching 'pip/cacert.pem'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rst' found under directory 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
Adding pip 1.5.2 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/bin

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
easy_install pip  3.96s user 3.16s system 76% cpu 9.367 total
```

Looks like it installed fine:

```
% which pip
/usr/bin/pip
% head -n1 `which pip`
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
% ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kwilliams 13 Dec 27 18:47 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7.exe*
```

Then I try to use pip to install something, and it seems to do nothing:

```
% pip install jinja2
% ls /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja*
zsh: no matches found: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja*
% python -c "import jinja2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jinja2
%
```

Am I misunderstanding how I'm supposed to use these tools?

Comment: It looks like it should work.  Try `/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install jinja2`

Comment: Same result with that, no output.

Comment: right after `%pip intall jinja2`, what does `% echo $?` output?

Comment: may be this is useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057931/pip-install-not-functioning-on-windows-7-cygwin-install

Comment: You may have been hit by following issue: ["`pip` command exits immediately on Cygwin #1448"](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1448)

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize jinja

```
pip install Jinja2
```